# How to customize django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I am building an e-commerce website and I would like to customize my Django Admin Panel to look something like this:
[image]

I would like to re-design the entire admin page and add graphs, tables images etc. the same way you would do on the front-end. I have been searching online for hours for a solution but I can't find anything useful. Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The django-admin pages can be customised, but not to the extent that you are hoping for. You would need to over-write a whole load of the built in django admin views, re-write a lot of the templates too.

By this point you would be re-writing so much of it, you would basically be writing your own admin anyway, and so it would be much much easier, not to use the admin app at all, and just write your own admin interface from scratch. From the docs:

> The admin has many hooks for customization, but beware of trying to
> use those hooks exclusively. If you need to provide a more
> process-centric interface that abstracts away the implementation
> details of database tables and fields, then it’s probably time to
> write your own views.

Remember also, that the admin app **is not designed to be a production ready interface**. It should ideally, only be used by developers, so if you are needing something to be used by a wider group, the admin app probably isn't appropriate anyway.

Sorry that this probably isn't the answer you were hoping for, but it will definitely be much easier to do this yourself, than try and bolt it onto something that is going to get in your way every step of the way.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for your reply. 
So just to clarify, are you saying that I have to create my own admin panel from scratch (write my own HTML CSS and javascript) the same way I would do with the front end? then let this new admin panel behave like the Django admin panel? Like how would my models and views work?
If this is the case, do you know any documentation or blog that I can follow to help me achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, more or less. You'd write a view for each page you want in your admin, and decorate them with the `user_passes_test` decorator to ensure that only apprpriate users can access those pages. I'm not aware of any documentation/blogs I'm afraid. Good luck though :)

Answer (score 0):

use pip install django-jazzmin

add 'jazzmin' to installed app in settings.py
make sure it above django.contrib.admin
'jazzmin',
'django.contrib.admin',